# Error during calling testCallfoo function using .call() keyword

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix, ethereumjs

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract Receiver {
    event Received(address caller, uint amount, string message);

    fallback() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value, "Fallback was called");
    }

    function foo(address payable _addr, uint amount) public payable returns (uint) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _addr.call{value: amount, gas: 5000}("");
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value, "_message");

        return amount;
    }
}

contract Caller {
    event Response(bool success, bytes data);

    // Let's imagine that contract Caller does not have the source code for the
    // contract Receiver, but we do know the address of contract Receiver and the function to call.
    function testCallFoo(address payable _addr, address to) public {
        // You can send ether and specify a custom gas amount
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _addr.call{ gas: 5000}(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("foo(address,uint256)", payable(to), 1)
        );
        emit Response(success, data);
    }

    // Calling a function that does not exist triggers the fallback function.
    function testCallDoesNotExist(address payable _addr) public payable {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _addr.call{value: msg.value}(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("doesNotExist()")
        );

        emit Response(success, data);
    }
}
```

I'm calling testCallfoo function to transfer ether from Receiver contract to an address but I'm getting initial error "reason provided by the contract: "failed to execute operation".". So can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue?

I just want to call testCallfoo function from Caller contract which interact with Receiver contract and transfer the ether from Receiver contract to an account, but I'm getting issues at abi.encodeWithSignature("transferEth(address, uint)", to, amount). so please help me out from this issues.